# Future<void> login failed to compile application

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I have an error in my code, causing this message:

"The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is potentially non-nullable. Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end."

The code is:

```
Future<Void> login() async {
    if (passController.text.isNotEmpty && emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse("https://www.sencommunity.id/apisen/mobile/cekLogin"),
          body: ({
            'email': emailController.text,
            'password': passController.text
          }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Second()));
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid Credentials")));
      }
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Black Field Not allowed")));
    }
  }
}
```

What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should not use `Void`, change it to `void` and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: I would upvote it for the Void/void part, but the second sentence is just dangerous advice and dead wrong.

Comment: @nvoigt i looked it up and you are right. thanks for noticing